# What will happen if I malloc a pointer of a struct datatype which contains an element of a pointer of another datatype?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management

Consider the following code:

```c
typedef struct list_ele
{
    char *value;
    struct list_ele *next;
}list_ele_t;

typedef struct
{
    list_ele_t *head;
    int qSize;
}queue_t;
```

And If I use a function to malloc a pointer of queue_t like this

```c
queue_t *q = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
```

What it actually happen? I mean, how big the memory it will create by malloc, should I use the following code

```c
q->head = malloc(sizeof(list_ele_t));
```

to apply for space for q->head?

I'm not good at C language (;w;) , I try my best to think but I got nothing.

Comment: An idiomatic way: `some_type *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));` Then, if `some_type` is ever changed, the statement "does the right thing" so no changes needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Stack         |       Heap
                  |
      q ----------|---> +------------+
                  |     + A chunk of +         
                  |     +   memory   +
                  |     +  equal to  +
                  |     +   sizeof   +
                  |     +   queue_t  +
(a pointer to     |     +------------+
 a struct of      |          / \
 type queue_t)    |         /   \ 
                  |        /     \  
                  |   qsize      head    
                  |                |
                  |                |
                  |                | 
                  |      +-----------+         
                  |      + Chunk of  +
                  |      + memory of +
                  |      + size list +
                  |      +-----------+
                  |
```

Side Notes:

1. The storage that is allocated through `malloc` is uninitialized.
2. `malloc` indicates failure by returning a `NULL` pointer value.
3. For every allocation, there must be a `free`.

Comment: Thanks! That's a very good picture of this problem! the head pointer contains "char *value", so that means If I want to store something in value I have to malloc the pointer of head and the pointer of value right?

Comment: Surely, if you want to allocate the memory they point to on the heap.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot, I think I know  the problem of my program!

Comment: Anytime. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

A C pointer is usually!!! 8 bytes so when you do

```
queue_t *q = malloc(sizeof(queue_t));
```

you allocate 8(pointer) + 4(int) + 4(padding, see bellow) (usually) bytes of memory and you have `q` point to it. `q->head` is going to point to a random location as you have not assigned anything to it. Of course when you do

```
q->head = malloc(sizeof(list_ele_t));
```

you allocate 8 + 8 (usually) bytes of memory and you point q->head to it. Also learn what [structure padding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306269/15460366) is:

```
sizeof(queue_t)    -> 16
sizeof(list_ele_t) -> 16
```

So you actually allocate more than 12 bytes for the memory that q points to.

Comment: @0130 see the edited anwer

Comment: "A C pointer is usually!!! 8 bytes" --> Doubtful. Note that billions of processors per year are embedded ones with 2 and 4 byte pointers.

Comment: @MagicThanos Thanks a lot, I forget the problem of padding

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica ah, that means pointers' size may probably be different when we use different processor?

Comment: @0130 Yes,  In C, object pointers are at least 16-bit.  In general, one should code in a way that pointer size is irrelevant.